# XDevApi How to Send Back the Result of .insert()

Tags: node.js, mysql-x-devapi

`.insert()` is successful, but the following resulting `{result:{}}` in Postman. How do I send the whole object in screen back so the client can query properties?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because the [`Result`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-Result.html) instance isn't directly serializable to JSON, which in the end, is the format that gets sent back to the client via the HTTP response. You need to build a plain JavaScript object on the server side containing whatever properties you need, which in turn will be properly serialized to JSON.

In the case of a regular [`insert()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-TableInsert.html), eventually, the only "interesting" data might be the number of items that were inserted, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` count (when it applies) and details about any warnings that have been generated. Everything else is not applicable to this kind of operation.

```
table.insert(/* something */)
  .execute()
  .then(out => {
    const json = {
      items: out.getAffectedItemsCount(),
      auto_increment: out.getAutoIncrementValue()
    }

    if (out.getWarningsCount() > 0) {
      json.warnings = out.getWarnings()
    }

    res.status(200).send(json)
  })
```

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js